# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error

Tags: android, sqlite

After I updated android version to 8(oreo), my aplication crashes when I start it.I use a db stored on external directory, and opened it with

private SQLiteDatabase db=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_PATH+DATABASE_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

AndroidManifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

After update I got this error

```
   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error (code 0)
#################################################################
Error Code : 0 (SQLITE_OK)
Caused By : not an error (code 0)
#################################################################
```

Comment: have you check your query?

Comment: what query, i can't open database, before update android it have worked fine

Comment: What do you mean by external Directory? do you mean SD Card? and which version were you using before updating it to Android 8?

Comment: post your SQL lite queries code

Comment: static File path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); here i put my db, before i used android 6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLiteException: not an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470182/sqliteexception-not-an-error)

Comment: not is dublicated